# directory hierarchy issue when using shutil.make_archive

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a zip archive of the `pip` package , code as following

```
import shutil
import os
import pip
shutil.make_archive(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'pipzip'), 'zip', root_dir=pip.__path__[0])
```

but when

```
shutil.unpack_archive(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'pipzip.zip'))
```

I got a list of files and folders in current directory, which originally resides in the pip package  , i.e.

```
['_internal', '_vendor', '__init__.py', '__main__.py', '__pycache__']
```

While  I hope there is a directory named `pip` to contain the list of files and folders when `shutil.unpack_archive`, so what adjustment to `shutil.make_archive` should I do ?

BTW, I cannot grasp the use of [shutil.make_archive](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.make_archive) even consulting the doc, I think the doc should update so that give a clear description .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were half way there. Basically you were specifying the *root_dir* and not the *base_dir*. You can do it by using the following snippet.

```
import shutil
import os
import pip
from pathlib import Path
shutil.make_archive(base_name=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'pipzip'), format='zip', root_dir=Path(pip.__path__[0]).parent, base_dir=Path(pip.__path__[0]).name)
shutil.unpack_archive(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'pipzip.zip'))
```